# SEO Impact when replacing html entity with unicode

Tags: seo, unicode

I am revamping my whole site in reactjs with server-side rendering. In the process, I am replacing all HTML entities in title and meta tags with Unicode.

- Old title example:

  > This is a &raquo; Title
- New title:

  > This is a » Title

Will it cause any negative impact on SEO?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No, it will not impact you negatively.

Long answer: Unicode is just a representation of characters from U+0000 to U+10FFFF. Nothing more. Google is able to understand that just as well as any other standard represention of characters. If you asked "how SEO friendly unicode URLs are", well that would be a matter of taste, language and target market. Amazon Japan uses unicode characters in their URLs due to nonexistent and/or unreadable URLs in ASCII representation. Same goes for some non-latin character languages such as Arabic, Hebrew, Farsi, Chinese, etc.

Comment: I agree with this.  Google is already decoding your entities.   Using unicode instead is equivalent from Google's perspective.  Google has always been very good about this.   When Yahoo ran its own search engine however, they couldn't deal with entities in titles or meta descriptions properly.

Answer (score -2):

No, it wont make any difference. Google knows how to handle Unicode characters.

We can think it in other way.

Even there is a chance of increased CTR and engagement by grabbing the attention using unicode characters. This high engagement may positively affect our SERP

Comment: This doesn't say anything the existing answer doesn't already say.  Do you have anything you can add to this that would make it useful?

Comment: I have not noticed the other answer. Now added some more info. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're talking about in your last paragraph. The question isn't about using Unicode versus not using it it's about using entity and coding or Unicode file encoding